# How to tell which words were found by Str::contains in laravel while searching for flagged words?

Tags: php, laravel, string

I am working on a feature where I need to find flagged words in some content, and I am using the in built laravel `Str::contains` to figure it out. It works like a charm, and easy to use.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
Str::contains($this->content, $flagged_words)
```

But it only gives me a boolean output. I also would like to know which flagged word it gave me when it comes `true`. Is that possible? Or will I have to find another way?

One way I can think of is to loop through the array of flagged words, and individually check for `Str::contains` on them. That way I will know which word was flagged. Any better ideas?

Comment: The solution you are thinking is correct, but you can try using `array_first` function in laravel `Arr::first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below; I'm sure it will be very beneficial.

```
    $flagged_words = ['first', 'second'];
    $content = "This my first string project.";

    $flagged_word = Arr::first($flagged_words, function ($word) use ($content) {
        return Str::contains($content, $word);
    });

    if ($flagged_word) {
        echo "Flagged word found:  ==> " . $flagged_word;
    } else {
        echo "No flagged words found.";
    }
```